# CGAL - cannot use import_from_polyhedron_3

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to simplify a surface read from .off file and view it using CGAL.
I read the surface as Polyhedron_3 and I want to convert it to Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map to view it but there is a problem in import_from_polyhedron_3 method

**my code:**

```
    typedef CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_combinatorial_map<2,3> LCC_3;
     typedef LCC_3::Dart_handle Dart_handle;

    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
    typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                       Polyhedron;
     QWidget* viewer ;
       QString fileName;

     LCC_3 lcc;
       QMainWindow qWin;
      CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorLCC fcolor;

      Polyhedron P;

void MainWindow::preview()
{

    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(viewer);
          centralWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
  CGAL::import_from_polyhedron_3<LCC_3, Polyhedron>(lcc, P);
          setCentralWidget( new CGAL::SimpleLCCViewerQt<LCC_3, CGAL::DefaultColorFunctorLCC>(&qWin ,
                      lcc,
                      "Basic LCC Viewer",
                      false,
                       fcolor ) );
    show();
}

    void MainWindow::fileOpen()
    {
       fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select object"), ".", tr("*.off"));
    std::ofstream out(fileName.toLocal8Bit());
        out<<P;
     preview();
}

    void MainWindow ::simplify()
    {

        bool ok;
        int n = QInputDialog::getInt(this, "", tr("Number of vertices in each cell:"),P.size_of_vertices(),0, P.size_of_vertices(),1, &ok);

        if (ok){
            int r = P.size_of_vertices() - n;
            int target_edges = P.size_of_halfedges()/2 - r*3;
        n=target_edges+1;
        }


        typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Surface;

        SaveOFF("temp.off");
        namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification ;
        Surface surface;
        std::ifstream is("temp.off") ; is >> surface ;

        // This is a stop predicate (defines when the algorithm terminates).
        // In this example, the simplification stops when the number of undirected edges
        // left in the surface drops below the specified number (1000)
        SMS::Count_stop_predicate<Surface> stop(n);

        // This the actual call to the simplification algorithm.
        // The surface and stop conditions are mandatory arguments.
        // The index maps are needed because the vertices and edges
        // of this surface lack an "id()" field.


        int r = SMS::edge_collapse
                  (surface
                  ,stop
                   ,CGAL::parameters::vertex_index_map(get(CGAL::vertex_external_index,surface))
                                     .halfedge_index_map  (get(CGAL::halfedge_external_index  ,surface))

    );
        std::ofstream os("temp.off"); os << surface ;
        OpenOFF("temp.off");

        std::cout << "Finished..." << r << " edges removed."<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<P.size_of_vertices()<<" Vertices"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<P.size_of_facets()<<" Facets"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<P.size_of_halfedges()<<" Halfedges"<<std::endl;
      preview();

     }
```

it shows me the following error: 
‘import_from_polyhedron_3’ is not a member of ‘CGAL’
    CGAL::import_from_polyhedron_3(lcc, P);

another problem it cannot reload the surface in the viewer after simplifying it , it shows the following error :
it's shows error "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system."

I need any help please 
thanks

Comment: Missing #include<CGAL/Polyhedron_3_to_lcc.h> ?

Comment: @gdamiand thanks a lot it solves the problem  :)

Comment: @gdamiand Have you any idea about reload the mesh viewer after simplification ? when I run the SimpleLCCViewerQt code after simplification it's shows error "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system."

Comment: Have a look at the linear cell complex demo (in the CGAL master branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing #include< CGAL/Polyhedron_3_to_lcc.h > (cf doc [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/group__PkgLinearCellComplexConstructions.html#ga9239e988c6d5e674d64438d47b95a548))